# Flex - what does Invalid url mean exactly and how to handle this fault?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, amf, fault

I am using flex remoting to php, and it works very well, except I occasionally get these 'Invalid URL' fault messages.

In the message below, notice it is using an ip address.   SO, no dns lookup issue.

There are usually minimum 10, up to 50 users logged in to this application at one time and there are only a few faults (not at the same time), so I dont think it was a server or larger network issue.

This particular message is to the PollService, so that tells me this user has already communicated with the server a number of times.  For example, to log in and to load across other data.    The polling is an every 10 seconds flex timer that calls the remote service.

SO, I am trying to figure out if this is an error on the server side, returning something flex did not like, or if it is in fact some lower level network/communications issue, OR possibly something else like an internal flex glitch?   Then I would like to figure out how to appropriately handle this fault - maybe re-transmit after a delay?

```
PollService Send failed Client.Error.MessageSend Channel.Connect.Failed error Invalid URL url: 
'http://172.16.10.26:80/amf/indexPoll.php' [ChannelFaultEvent faultCode="Channel.Connect.Failed"     
faultString="error" faultDetail="Invalid URL url: 'http://172.16.10.26:80/amf/indexPoll.php'" channelId=null 
type="channelFault" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
```

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you have an error on your server. try looking in your server logs. Also try using a packet sniffer to see what's going on between Flex and your server. An article that goes into more detail on packet sniffers : http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/documentation/using-a-packet-sniffer/ The tool I recommend : http://www.charlesproxy.com/

Comment: agree, looks like possibly a server issue, maybe php is erroring out, but I am seeing no php errors logged.   It does not happen often enough to catch with a sniffer (I use fiddler).   was hoping someone might have some other ideas what this could indicate, or thoughts on how to debug

Comment: Well you know how it goes, to be able to fix you need to be able to reproduce :-)